# Is it common to denote zero map (e.g. $\forall x, \phi(x)=0$) by $\phi = 0$?

Tags: functions, notation

Is it common to denote zero map (e.g. $\forall x, \phi(x)=0$) just by $\phi = 0$? I found similar notation on my textbook but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes. Also common to write $f\equiv0$, which I would read as "identically zero" (meaning the same thing).

Comment: Sometimes the notation $ \phi \equiv  0$ is used.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, $f(x)=0$, $f=0$ and $f\equiv 0$ are all common. To explain the idea behind the notations:

$f\equiv 0$ means "identically zero", meaning "is $0$ at all values of $x$". I mostly think of real/complex functions when I see this.

With $f=0$, we regard $0$ as a function rather than a value; the function $f$ is the function $0$ (or rather the zero function as we usually call it).